# MySql get data from multiple tables results from a select

Tags: mysql, select, multi-table

I have a table "move" like this

```
----------------------------------
| id | ... | ... |  tab  | idTab |
----------------------------------
| 1  | ... | ... | bike  |  14   |
| 2  | ... | ... | car   |  57   |
| 3  | ... | ... | car   |  23   |
| 4  | ... | ... | bike  |  43   |
| 5  | ... | ... | boat  |  20   |
| .. | ... | ... | ...   | ....  |
----------------------------------
```

tab "bike"

```
---------------------------------
| id | code | name  | matr | ... |
---------------------------------
| .. | ...  | ....  | .... | ... |
| 14 | AAA  | MARIO | 111  | ... |
| .. | ...  | ....  | .... | ... |
| 43 | A1C  | JOHN  | EEE  | ... |
| .. | ...  | ....  | .... | ... |
---------------------------------
```

tab "car"

```
---------------------------------
| id | code | name  | matr | ... |
---------------------------------
| .. | ...  | ....  | .... | ... |
| 23 | 123  | JACK  | WER  | ... |
| .. | ...  | ....  | .... | ... |
| 57 | 2A2  | FRANK | MSS  | ... |
| .. | ...  | ....  | .... | ... |
---------------------------------
```

tab "boat"

```
---------------------------------
| id | code | name  | matr | ... |
---------------------------------
| .. | ...  | ....  | .... | ... |
| 20 | UJN  | PETER | WSX  | ... |
| .. | ...  | ....  | .... | ... |
---------------------------------
```

I would like to have in a single query all datas of "move" and the datas of each tables present in "move" with specific idTab.

The result will be like this

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| id | ... | ... |  tab  | idTab | code | name  | matr | ... |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | ... | ... | bike  |  14   | AAA  | MARIO | 111  | ... |
| 2  | ... | ... | car   |  57   | 2A2  | FRANK | MSS  | ... |
| 3  | ... | ... | car   |  23   | 123  | JACK  | WER  | ... |
| 4  | ... | ... | bike  |  43   | A1C  | JOHN  | EEE  | ... |
| 5  | ... | ... | boat  |  20   | UJN  | PETER | WSX  | ... |
| .. | ... | ... | ...   | ....  | ...  | ....  | .... | ... |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't know in effect if I have or not a specific table in move. 
I can make a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM move WHERE id>0
```

and then a foreach with

```
SELECT * FROM move["tab"] WHERE id=move["idTab"]
```

but is very hard work because table move is very long...

I try with this but (obviously) don't work...

```
SELECT M.*, T.* FROM move as M, M.tab as T WHERE M.id>0 AND M.idTab=T.id
```

Comment: Why not store all common columns in a single table

Comment: @Strawberry Because then SO users would not have any work to do, and we obviously don't want _that_ :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database design is not ideal, and I don't think you should be having separate tables for each type of vehicle.  That being said, if you bring the three tables into a single one using a `UNION`, then a single join could yield your desired result.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM move t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, code, name, matr, 'bike' AS tab
    FROM bike
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, code, name, matr, 'car'
    FROM car
    SELECT id, code, name, matr, 'boat'
    FROM boat
) t2
    ON t1.idTab = t2.id AND
       t1.tab   = t2.tab
```

I added a computed column for the type of table under the assumption that perhaps the same `id` could appear in more than one vehicle table.

Comment: Thanks... I have more table that contains more informations of vehicles and a table like join of these with general informations.

Comment: @FrancescoG. ...and your question is?

Comment: it's only to explain because I have designed like this my dbase. just wondering, if (for example)  I will haven't in "move" an item "boat", the query will work?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 'bike' vehicle,column1,.... from bike
Union
Select 'boat',column1,... from boat
Union...
```